# How to send a custom email containing TFS Build status

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'd like to send a custom build status email during or after the TFS build, but it doesn't look like the actual compilation status, etc. is known until after the entire process ends. Does anyone know of a way to send a custom email (other than the built-in alert email) that has the true build status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the notification web services in TFS to built an app that will recieve the web service notifications, and then do what ever you want; e.g. request the full build status, parse logs, add a spinning bear.

There are some details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/narend/archive/2006/07/27/679571.aspx)

Comment: @dhopton

The subscription looks like the way to go, since I can subscribe to the event fired once the end-to-end Team Foundation Build process has completed/failed/etc. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the "Build Notification Tray app, which is part of the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx)? This is able to give immediate build failure feedback.